Rider IDE - AWS Toolkit bug for creating Lambda Functions
I have a problem that i dont really understand.
I am new to AWS, and I am trying to use the AWS Toolkit to upload a simple AWS Lambda (.net 6) function.
Please forgive me if this is something obvious that im simply missing.
Let me try to describe my problem:
I am user Rider IDE, i added the AWS Toolkit plugin.
I created a new Lambda Empty Serverless project to test the basic things.
I am following the Tutorial in the AWS Docs about using the .NET Lambda Global CLI, so far everything works fine. I successfully was able to create and upload a basic lambda function.
However, when i try to use the AWS Toolkit Plugin, things do not work. When i open the AWS Toolkit Plugin, click on "Explorer", then navigate to the "Create Function" UI, and right click on "Lambda" to open the "Create new AWS Lambda..." dialogue, my IDE gives me the error that I will link at the bottom of my post.
Even though the error happens, i can still open the "Create new AWS Lambda..." dialogue. However, i can only select nodejs runetimes.
I am not sure why this is the case (or if it even has something to with the error).
But because the error says [...Cannot create extension (class=software.aws.toolkits.jetbrains.services.lambda.python.PythonRuntimeGroup) [Plugin: aws.toolkit] ...] my intuition is, that first, the nodejs runetimes get loaded, and after that, the python runetime is maybe next? And possibly, because it crashes, all following runtimes get skipped?
I found this post about a similar issue.
I tried the suggested solution:
The solution for me was also to add the environment variable 
DOTNET_ROOT and let it point to => %USERPROFILE%\.dotnet

but it did not change anything.
Thank you very much!
The error my IDE gives me:
com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: Cannot create extension (class=software.aws.toolkits.jetbrains.services.lambda.python.PythonRuntimeGroup) [Plugin: aws.toolkit]
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.createError(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:988)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.XmlExtensionAdapter.doCreateInstance(XmlExtensionAdapter.kt:73)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.XmlExtensionAdapter.createInstance(XmlExtensionAdapter.kt:33)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl.processAdapter(ExtensionPointImpl.kt:395)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl.createExtensionInstances(ExtensionPointImpl.kt:368)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl.getExtensionList(ExtensionPointImpl.kt:214)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.ExtensionPointName.getExtensionList(ExtensionPointName.kt:54)
    at software.aws.toolkits.jetbrains.services.lambda.RuntimeGroup$Companion.registeredRuntimeGroups(RuntimeGroup.kt:85)
    at software.aws.toolkits.jetbrains.services.lambda.RuntimeGroupExtensionPointObject.supportedRuntimeGroups(RuntimeGroup.kt:125)
    at software.aws.toolkits.jetbrains.services.lambda.upload.CreateLambdaFunctionAction.update(CreateLambdaFunctionAction.kt:58)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$performDumbAwareUpdate$runnable$1.invoke(ActionUtil.kt:162)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$performDumbAwareUpdate$runnable$1.invoke(ActionUtil.kt:155)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performDumbAwareUpdate(ActionUtil.kt:180)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionUpdater$updateAction$success$1$1$1.invoke(ActionUpdater.kt:564)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionUpdater$updateAction$success$1$1$1.invoke(ActionUpdater.kt:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionUpdater$callAction$2$1.invoke(ActionUpdater.kt:151)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.rw.InternalReadAction.insideReadAction(InternalReadAction.kt:108)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.rw.InternalReadAction.access$insideReadAction(InternalReadAction.kt:16)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.rw.InternalReadAction$tryReadCancellable$2.invoke(InternalReadAction.kt:95)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.rw.InternalReadAction$tryReadCancellable$2.invoke(InternalReadAction.kt:94)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.rw.CancellableReadActionKt$cancellableReadActionInternal$1.invoke$lambda$1$lambda$0(cancellableReadAction.kt:38)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.RwLockHolder.tryRunReadAction(RwLockHolder.kt:310)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.tryRunReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:958)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.rw.CancellableReadActionKt$cancellableReadActionInternal$1.invoke$lambda$1(cancellableReadAction.kt:36)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressIndicatorUtilService.runActionAndCancelBeforeWrite(ProgressIndicatorUtilService.java:66)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressIndicatorUtils.runActionAndCancelBeforeWrite(ProgressIndicatorUtils.java:155)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.rw.CancellableReadActionKt$cancellableReadActionInternal$1.invoke(cancellableReadAction.kt:34)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.CoroutinesKt.blockingContextInner(coroutines.kt:320)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.CoroutinesKt.blockingContext(coroutines.kt:309)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.rw.CancellableReadActionKt.cancellableReadActionInternal(cancellableReadAction.kt:31)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.rw.InternalReadAction.tryReadCancellable(InternalReadAction.kt:94)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.rw.InternalReadAction.tryReadAction(InternalReadAction.kt:78)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.rw.InternalReadAction.readLoop(InternalReadAction.kt:65)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.rw.InternalReadAction.access$readLoop(InternalReadAction.kt:16)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.rw.InternalReadAction$runReadAction$3.invokeSuspend(InternalReadAction.kt:36)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.rw.InternalReadAction$runReadAction$3.invoke(InternalReadAction.kt)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.rw.InternalReadAction$runReadAction$3.invoke(InternalReadAction.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startUndispatchedOrReturn(Undispatched.kt:78)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScopeKt.coroutineScope(CoroutineScope.kt:264)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.rw.InternalReadAction.runReadAction(InternalReadAction.kt:35)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.rw.PlatformReadWriteActionSupport.executeReadAction(PlatformReadWriteActionSupport.kt:38)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.ReadWriteActionSupport.executeReadAction$default(ReadWriteActionSupport.kt:15)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.CoroutinesKt.constrainedReadActionUndispatched(coroutines.kt:82)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.CoroutinesKt.readActionUndispatched(coroutines.kt:69)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionUpdater$callAction$$inlined$useWithScope$1.invokeSuspend(trace.kt:151)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionUpdater$callAction$$inlined$useWithScope$1.invoke(trace.kt)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionUpdater$callAction$$inlined$useWithScope$1.invoke(trace.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startUndispatchedOrReturn(Undispatched.kt:78)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.withContext(Builders.common.kt:167)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.withContext(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionUpdater.callAction(ActionUpdater.kt:863)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionUpdater.access$callAction(ActionUpdater.kt:80)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionUpdater$updateAction$success$1$1.invokeSuspend(ActionUpdater.kt:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionUpdater$updateAction$success$1$1.invoke(ActionUpdater.kt)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionUpdater$updateAction$success$1$1.invoke(ActionUpdater.kt)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ActionUpdaterInterceptor.updateAction$suspendImpl(ActionUpdaterInterceptor.kt:19)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ActionUpdaterInterceptor.updateAction(ActionUpdaterInterceptor.kt)
    at com.jetbrains.rider.actions.RiderActionUpdateInterceptor.updateAction(RiderActionUpdateInterceptor.kt:30)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionUpdater$updateAction$$inlined$retryOnAwaitSharedData$1.invokeSuspend(ActionUpdater.kt:863)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionUpdater$updateAction$$inlined$retryOnAwaitSharedData$1.invoke(ActionUpdater.kt)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionUpdater$updateAction$$inlined$retryOnAwaitSharedData$1.invoke(ActionUpdater.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startUndispatchedOrReturn(Undispatched.kt:78)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.withContext(Builders.common.kt:167)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.withContext(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionUpdater.updateAction(ActionUpdater.kt:888)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionUpdater.expandGroupChild(ActionUpdater.kt:412)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionUpdater.access$expandGroupChild(ActionUpdater.kt:80)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionUpdater$doExpandActionGroup$2$expandResult$1$1$1.invokeSuspend(ActionUpdater.kt:339)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:108)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher$Worker.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:115)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:103)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:584)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:793)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:697)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:684)
Caused by: com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: Class com.jetbrains.python.PythonLanguage must not be requested from main classloader of PythonCore plugin. Matches content module (packagePrefix=com.jetbrains.python., moduleName=intellij.python.community.impl). [Plugin: aws.toolkit]
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.tryLoadingClass(PluginClassLoader.kt:203)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.kt:151)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    at software.aws.toolkits.jetbrains.services.lambda.python.PythonRuntimeGroup.<init>(PythonRuntimeGroup.kt:20)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.findConstructorAndInstantiateClass(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:908)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.doInstantiateClass(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:917)
    at com.intellij.serviceContainer.ComponentManagerImpl.instantiateClass(ComponentManagerImpl.kt:902)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.SimpleConstructorInjectionAdapter.instantiateClass(XmlExtensionAdapter.kt:103)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.XmlExtensionAdapter.doCreateInstance(XmlExtensionAdapter.kt:52)
    ... 74 more



It seems to be a known issue on the Amazon's side:
Toolkit causes exception in Ultimate 2022.1.4 on installation of JetBrains Go Plugin. #3224
Please feel free to either continue the thread posted or create a new one on the Amazon GitHub tracker.
